# S3 Bucket Policy - Deny Bucket Delete returning "Invalid policy syntax"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to prevent the accidental deletion of my S3 bucket. Using the policy generator I came up with this policy:

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1611547079478",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1611547073630",
      "Action": [
        "s3:DeleteBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*",
      "Principal": "*",
    }
  ]
}
```

However, when I attempt to save the policy I get the error:

`Unknown Error An unexpected error occurred. API response Invalid policy syntax.`

I already have a bucket policy in place to make the bucket public for hosting images. Here is the full code:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
},

{
  "Id": "Policy1611547079478",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1611547073630",
      "Action": [
        "s3:DeleteBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*",
      "Principal": "*",
    }
  ]
}
```

The public bucket policy works, when I add the deny delete bucket policy I get the error.

Comment: `DeleteBucket` is for `arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name`, not `arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*`. But are you sure that you want to do this? This will deny even you to delete this bucket.

Comment: The full code that you showed is the actual bucket policy, it is just  formatting issue on SO?

Comment: I tried that but I am still getting the error message. My thought is that if I really wanted to delete the bucket I could go into Permissions and delete the "Deny Delete" policy. I am really just trying to protect myself from accidentally clicking the wrong button or worse my 4 yo son button mashing on my computer one day... lol

Comment: You can't delete bucket with objects in it that easly. First you would have to delete all objects, before you can delete the bucket. The policy does not protect you from deleting the objects anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bucket policy in your question has incorrect form. It should be:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1611547073630",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:DeleteBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name"
        }
    ]
}
```

Since in the first statement you are allowing public access, you will also have to disable `Block all public access`.

Comment: Wonderful, this did the trick. Thank you very much!

Comment: @IsaacTait No problem. Glad it worked out:-)